# Invocation of multiprocessing in Python 3.11 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

I have a problem with multiprocessing in Python 3.11 on Windows.

Here is the script:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import time

def info(title):
        print(title)
        print('module name:', __name__)
        if hasattr(os, 'getppid'):  # only available on Unix
               print('parent process:', os.getppid())
        print('process id:', os.getpid())

def f(name):
        info('function f')
        print('--- hello', name)
        time.sleep(5)
        print('--- bye', name)

def some_func():
        print('Running some_func function')

def another_func():
        print('Running another_func function')


def main():
        print('Running main function of try_multi.py')
        print('-------------------------------------')
        some_func()
        if __name__ == '__main__':
               info('main line')
               p1 = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
               p2 = Process(target=f, args=('larry',))
               p1.start()
               p2.start()
               p1.join()
               p2.join()
        another_func()

main()
```

Here is it's output:

```
C:\Scripts> c:\Python31\python.exe try_multi.py
Running main function of try_multi.py
-------------------------------------
Running some_func function
main line
module name: __main__
process id: 12696
Running main function of try_multi.py
-------------------------------------
Running some_func function
Running another_func function
function f
module name: __main__
process id: 14568
--- hello bob
Running main function of try_multi.py
-------------------------------------
Running some_func function
Running another_func function
function f
module name: __main__
process id: 9336
--- hello larry
--- bye bob
--- bye larry
Running another_func function
```

The problem is that I expect only function "f" to run in the new processes but it looks like the whole new instance of the parent script is started - both "some_fun" and "another_func" run.

On Linux with Python 2.7.5 it works as expected:

```
$ python try_multi.py
Running main function of try_multi.py
-------------------------------------
Running some_func function
main line
('module name:', '__main__')
('parent process:', 1137)
('process id:', 1167)
function f
('module name:', '__main__')
('parent process:', 1167)
('process id:', 1168)
('--- hello', 'bob')
function f
('module name:', '__main__')
('parent process:', 1167)
('process id:', 1169)
('--- hello', 'larry')
('--- bye', 'bob')
('--- bye', 'larry')
Running another_func function
```

Can I cause it work correctly on my platform (Python 3.11 on Windows)?
Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Python 3.1? This is a really ancient version (older than 2.7).

Comment: I need to run it on Windows 2008 and this is the newest Python version I succeeded to get working without installing any additional packages like MS runtime libraries. I do not want to install them because I cannot risk my production system.

Comment: Honestly, if you can't use at least Python 3.2, you're probably better off with 2.7 (or maybe even 2.6…). Especially if you're already using 2.7 on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in [Programming Guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) in the docs:

> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a new process).

In general, what this means is that you want to change the last line of your script from this:

```
main()
```

… to this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Otherwise, every new child process will start up and immediately try to call `main` and spawn two new processes. Whether this only goes on deep, or goes infinitely deep and forkbombs your system, or raises an exception depends on all kinds of details that aren't worth getting into, but it will never do the right thing on Windows.

---

If you're wondering why it works on Linux: On Windows, `multiprocessing` works by launching a completely new Python interpreter and making it import and run your module, so all the top-level code in the module gets run; on Linux, it works by forking a copy of the current interpreter process and then starting the task from there, so it doesn't actually need to rerun the script, so the top-level code usually doesn't get re-executed.

In later versions of Python (3.1 is really ancient…), they've cleaned things up a bit, and made them a bit more flexible, so you can do nice things like get the same behavior on both platforms by specifying `set_start_method('spawn')`. But the basic default results will be the same.